# How to disable the talkback green point when use ExploreByTouchHelper

Tags: android, youtube, talkback, google-text-to-speech, cobalt

I want to use my own view display, to make the left,ringht, up, down key pad work when the TV talkback is ON.
I try more method, but all can't work.
I also try to use ExploreByTouchHelper , same as the Youtube cobalt, https://github.com/youtube/cobalt/blob/main/starboard/android/apk/app/src/main/java/dev/cobalt/coat/CobaltA11yHelper.java
This method can make the key work when talkback enable, but it will always show a green point, when I press the pad key, the green point also can move. So How can I disable the green point.

Comment: afaik "green point" is telling user that microphone (or camera if present) is on and working. this can't be disabled for security and privacy reasons...

Comment: But when I use ExploreByTouchHelper , my apk will always show a green point, the youtube is OK, don't have a green point at upper left corner of the TV，this is why ? My delegate view also set color as transparent。